# MYSQL forward engineer error ENGINE = InnoDB error

Tags: mysql

ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 1

why is this error?

Comment: You need to include the entire statement that is resulting in the error. For example, if it is a Create Table statement then include that entire statement as part of your question.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What's the SQL statement that produces the error?